# Require git add before git commit

Tags: git

I'm new to git but my understanding was that you must add modified files to the index using `git add` before you would be allowed to commit them to the repository using `git commit`. I just modified a couple files and typed `git commit` on them forgetting to add them to the index first and found to my surprise that they got committed. What have I screwed up in my config that is allowing this to happen?

I'm using git version 2.5.0.windows.1.

I am not using `git commit -a.` I have tried this a few different ways. The following result in committing a modified (unstaged file):
`git commit file1` and `git commit .`.

I also just tried `git commit` with no parameters and this time the command did stop and tell me the files need to be staged first.

I know that the commits are happening because I run `git status` and can see the files are no longer modified. These are files that I have typically been doing `git add` and `git commit .` to all along in this project so I recognize how it looks differently when they're modified vs staged.

I am to the point now that I've done enough testing in another repository that I suspect there is some config setting. Here is what I have:

```
$ git config --list
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=true
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
diff.tool=bc
difftool.prompt=false
difftool.bc.trustexitcode=true
difftool.bc.cmd='c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe' $LOCAL     $REMOTE
merge.tool=bc
mergetool.prompt=false
mergetool.bc.trustexitcode=true
mergetool.bc.cmd='c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 4/bcomp.exe' $LOCAL     $REMOTE $BASE $MERGED
rerere.enabled=false
core.trustctime=false
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -notabbar -    multiInst
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
gui.wmstate=normal
gui.geometry=887x427+25+25 171 192
```

Comment: Where did the files come from? Were they created by you? Also, did you give any options to the `git commit`? Did you run any other git commands before that, which might have affected the files? (And for completeness, how do you know they were committed?)

Comment: Also. and you share your git config file?

Comment: There is also the possibility that you did `git add` at an earlier stage, and in this case, they have been only partially committed. What does `git status` say about the state of your working directory? Are the file clean?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful suggestions. Yes, I created and continue to modify these files. See edits above with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify paths on the commit command, git ignores any indexed changes and commits just those paths using their current worktree content (which also gets staged aka added aka indexed).  For some reason the paths must already be tracked.

Comment: Well I'll be darned. Thanks for pointing this out! Sure enough it's right here on item 3: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit. I didn't expect that behavior at all.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that you accidentally included the `-a` switch? With `git commit -a`, you automatically add modified files before comitting (this will add any modified files that git is tracking, but won't add files that git never saw before) So that is exactly like the behaviour you describe.